# Rewriting css style path

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

How can I rewrite urls of css styles from "http://myurl.com:454/css/style.css" to "http://myotherurl.com/css/style.css"?

Here´s my config

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine  on
    RewriteRule ^myurl\.com:454$  myotherurl.com [PT]

</IfModule>
```

Comment: Are you able to access your site on `http://myurl.com:454/` ?

Comment: Not from the DMZ, the url http://myurl.com:454/ can be accessed from the http server

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
RewriteEngine  On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}   ^myurl\.com$
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} ^454$
RewriteRule ^css/(.*)\.css$  http://myotherurl.com/$0 [L, R=301]
```

Comment: I have subfolders on the css folder, this would do the job for subfolders also?